# GreedySorting in python

Tags: python, algorithm, greedy

I'm defining a Python function which execute the greedy sorting.
(Bioinformatics Algorithms I, 2014, Coursera - [Stepic 6.4](https://stepic.org/lesson/A-Greedy-Algorithm-for-Sorting-by-Reversals-286/step/1?course=Bioinformatics-Algorithms&unit=490))

The result of sorting should be [+1, +2, +3, +4, +5] and the function should return all the steps of changes from initial input list, too.

To sort initial input list, several steps of reversal are essential. It is much like [pancake flipping problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancake_sorting). In this question, signed permutation ([-3,+4,+1,+5,-2]) should be changed to identity signed permutation ([+1, +2, +3, +4, +5]).

Sample Input:

```
 [-3, +4, +1, +5, -2]
```

Sample Output:

```
[[-1, -4, +3, +5, -2],    
 [+1, -4, +3, +5, -2],    # -1  ->  +1
 [+1, +2, -5, -3, +4],    # reversal of (-4, +3, +5, -2)
 [+1, +2, +3, +5, +4],    # reversal of (-5, -3)
 [+1, +2, +3, -4, -5],    # reversal of (+5, +4)
 [+1, +2, +3, +4, -5],    # -4  ->  +4  
 [+1, +2, +3, +4, +5]]    # -5  ->  +5   Sorting finished!
```

I wrote a function but it's result was not correct.

```
# Implementation
def reversing(seq):
    """
    >>> reversing([+1,+2,-3,-4])
        [+4,+3,-2,-1]
    """
    seq.reverse()
    seq = map(lambda(x): -x, seq)
    return seq


def greedySorting1(lst):
    """
    ApproxReversalDistance (ARD)
    Return a number (ARD) until the result is [1,2,...,n]
    >>> greedySorting1([1,-5,3,-2,-4])
        6
    """
    change = []
    ARD = 0

    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[i] != i+1:
            if i+1 in lst:
                id_i = lst.index(abs(i+1)) 
            else:
                id_i = lst.index(-abs(i+1))
            lst = lst[:i] + reversing(lst[i:id_i+1]) + lst[id_i+1:]
            ARD += 1
            change.append(lst)
        if lst[i] == -(i+1):
            lst[i] = i+1
            ARD += 1
            change.append(lst)

    return change   




# Testing
print greedySorting([-3,+4,+1,+5,-2])

    [[+1, -4, +3, +5, -2],    # Wrong: +1 should be -1
     [+1, -4, +3, +5, -2], 
     [+1, +2, -5, -3, +4], 
     [+1, +2, +3, +5, +4], 
     [+1, +2, +3, +4, -5],    # Wrong: +4 should be -4
     [+1, +2, +3, +4, -5], 
     [+1, +2, +3, +4, +5]]
```

How can I fix my code to get correct answer like sample output?
Thanks.

Comment: basically your goal is get `([+1, +2, +3, +4, +5])` as output and print all of the steps untill reach this? Can we use everything we want?

Comment: I can get the final sorted result ([+1, +2, +3, +4, +5]), but I think that the whole steps can explain the greedy sorting algorithm in this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are modifying `lst` in-place, so any references to it in `change` will reflect that same change

```
if lst[i] == -(i+1):
```

You can make sure to "decouple" the lists in `change` by using `lst[:]` to make a copy

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if lst[i] != i+1:
        if i+1 in lst:
            id_i = lst.index(abs(i+1)) 
        else:
            id_i = lst.index(-abs(i+1))
        lst = lst[:i] + reversing(lst[i:id_i+1]) + lst[id_i+1:]
        ARD += 1
        change.append(lst[:])
    if lst[i] == -(i+1):
        lst[i] = i+1
        change.append(lst[:])
```

Now you can also simplify this line:

```
lst = lst[:i] + reversing(lst[i:id_i+1]) + lst[id_i+1:]
```

to

```
lst[i: id_i + 1] = reversing(lst[i: id_i + 1])
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help, John.

Answer (score 1):

When I solved this problem, I found it much easier to solve with the signs and numbers in two, matched index arrays, and making a copy of the list and the signs on each iteration to use as a reference (doesn't hurt as much as you think in terms of runtime/memory alloc.

One more thing that will help you is to use a nested for loop, to help you keep track of the switching of the numbers and signs inside the "reversal".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think that I'm missing some important concept in list copying in Python. I have to learn more about it.